# Sound BlasterX G1 low volume unless configuration is changed

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

I'm using onboard sourd card with loudspeakers at day and **Sound BlasterX G1** with headphones at night. When I connect G1 to USB port, sound volume is too low and kinda muffled.

Bu after I open Sound BlasterX Acoustic Engine Pro software (version 1.02.16), go to Advanced settings, and switch "Speakers / Headphones configuration" from whatever-current-setting-is to whatever-new-setting, volume jumps up significantly and sound is much more clear.

[image]

What can I do to skip the manual step and get clear sound automatically?

Edit: it is always too silent after G1 is attached, no matter what the last setting was. I have to switch from "headphone stereo" to "heatphone virtual 5.1" or the other way around (or switch twice to keep current setting).

Comment: I think you mean *from whatever-current-setting-is* (other than headphone) to "headphone", isn't it? That makes sense because the default for the port is LINE-OUT which expects external amplification.

Comment: Nope, it is always too silent after G1 is attached, no matter what the last setting was. I have to switch from "headphone stereo" to "headphone virtual 5.1" or the other way around (or switch twice to keep current setting).

Comment: Use Sound BlasterX G1: X-Plus Configurator to change internally programmed sound profile.
Apparently, default is set to Generic (PlayStation 4), which has some volume issues for generic usage.

Comment: Yessss!!! Thanks @RomanZhuzha! Would you mind changing your comment to an answer? Also please add, that changing profile can cause headphones gain change from 16-64 to 64-300 Ohm, so check that before sound testing.

Comment: I need more reputation for adding answer. It says that this is "Highly active question" and I need at least 10 reputation for answering it.

Comment: What a nonsense. Please post your answer when question is no longer "highly active", I will accept it instead of mine.

Comment: Will do. I'm happy I was able to help even after almost a year :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Following solution was provided by @RomanZhuzha, who is unable to enter it himself:**

Use Sound BlasterX G1: X-Plus Configurator to change internally programmed sound profile. Apparently, default is set to Generic (PlayStation 4), which has some volume issues for generic usage.

**Added by me**: changing profile can cause headphones gain setting skip from 16-64 to 64-300 Ohm, so check that in "BlasterX Acoustic Engine Pro" before sound testing